# Baked normal map showing seams at uv island boundaries

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normal-map

I'm trying to bake sculpt info into a normal map so that I can use it on my retopologised model.  I baked the normal map from the sculpt to the model using model's tangent space.  I then added the normal map to the normal input of the model's shader.  However, I'm getting some pretty sharp seams that corespond to the boundaries of my uv islands.

If I apply the normal map as a texture, there are visible seams at uv island boundaries, so maybe the normal map is being baked incorrectly?

My node set up and shader settings are visible in the attached image.  How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I needed to set my texture node's color-space field to `non-color data`. After that, it worked.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.